# jquery cookie not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey people i'm using a jquery plugin for creating cookies which seems to be working perfect when i run it on localhost but when I tested in the server it's not working as i expected.

below is my file testcookie.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="3.ico">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/iepngfix_tilebg.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script> 
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {

$.cookie("example", "foo");
alert( $.cookie("example") );

});})(jQuery);
</script>
</head>
<body>hello there</body>
</html>
```

result= no alert

here's the demo
http://namadda.com/demo/testcookie.php

onething i noticed just now is that click view source and all the script link is working but jquery.cookie.js isn't showing up, instead i'm getting error 406 when i clicked jquery cooke link on view source page. But it's present on server like other plugins.

Comment: What is not working? The value of the cookie is not being shown?

Comment: can you create jsfiddle use case to demonstrate it doesn't work?

Comment: And what are you expectations? Do you use an IE or a different browser? As concerned as IE this explorer has different page zones with different security options. Check these first if cookies are allowed in your zone, when the page was on the server.

Comment: Unless you are looking for cross site usage I'd look into HTML5 localStorage and sessionStorage as a more long term solution. Especially as some countries will in the future require websites to ask explicit permission to store cookies on someone's computer. Check out [Amplify.js](http://amplifyjs.com/) for an easy JQuery implementation.

Comment: it gives you undefined???? or do you have a error report for us

Comment: i solved this problem by renaming the file jquery.cookie.js

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The best solution is renaming jquery.cookie.js file to something like jquery_cookie.js

It was the best solution for me, because I don't have permission to modify mod_security

Comment: What does mod_security have to do with this? Can you explain why renaming the file all of the sudden works?

Comment: Works for me in Magento2 I just renamed my file from jquery.cookie.js to jquery-cookie.js

Answer (score 5):

1. Make sure that the JQuery and `js/jquery.cookie.js` js files exist at the server.<sup>[1]</sup>
2. Set the expiry date, so that the cookie doesn't get destroyed after the session.
3. Set a path, so that your cookie is accessible from your whole site (optional).

Combining 2 and 3: `$.cookie("example", "foo", {expires:7, path:"/"})` - Life time of 7 days

<sup>[1]</sup> *A common novice mistake*.

Comment: I forgot the expires setting which made firefox/safari destroy the cookie when the browser was closed, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Renaming the file `jquery.cookie.js` to something else should succeed.

Answer (score 1):

When I visit http://namadda.com/demo/js/jquery.cookie.js I get a 406 Not Acceptable HTTP error.

> An appropriate representation of the requested resource
>   /demo/js/jquery.cookie.js could not be found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Something is not configured properly on your server.